# How to update the attribute in render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When componentDidUpdate occurs I want to change attribute for example label of an element. I'm able to change the value of an element but not the label of it.

this is the element I'm trying to change which is rendered already. Should I re-render it?

```
var _phone = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'phone',
  label: 'Phone#:',
  value: values.phone || '',
  onChange: this.onChange
};
var _address = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'address',
  label: 'Address:',
  value: values.address || '',
  onChange: this.onChange
};
```

some part is here:

```
componentDidUpdate = function(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { values } = this.state;
  if (JSON.stringify(prevState.values) !== JSON.stringify(values)) {
    if (
        values.lkp_language != '' && 
        values.lkp_language !== prevState.values.lkp_language && 
        values.lkp_language * 1 == 1 
      ) {

        _lkp_participant_type.label = 'test'
        var comps = {
            _lkp_participant_type: _lkp_participant_type
        }

        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState,
            values: { ...prevState.values,
              ...comps
            }
          }
        });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey can you please share the entire code or a small snippet so that we can check what's the issue?. Thanks.

Comment: @kunalpanchal I've componentDidUpdate part of it